# Move WooCommerce Bundle Product add to cart section above short description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle, hook-woocommerce

I'm using a plugin named WooCommerce product bundle and want to move for bundled products the single add to card template above the excerpt *(short description)*.

I guess it's implemented by this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'wc_pb_template_add_to_cart_after_summary', -1000 );
```

But if I use `remove_action` in my theme's functions.php file, it's not working. When I removed it from the original file in wc-pb-template-hooks.php it worked.

So after it I want to add it to the Product Summary, but it's not working. Can somebody help, even by telling how to remove it from After Summary? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move single add to cart location above the product short description for bundle products, use the following instead:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'change_single_add_to_cart_bundle_location', 1 );
function change_single_add_to_cart_bundle_location(){
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('bundle') ) {
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );
        add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 15 );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).

Tested and works on Storefront theme and WordPress base themes *(with the standard layout and default form location in the "Bundled Products" tab settings)*.

Comment: Thank you for your solution. Unfortunately it's not working with my theme, but I works very well with Wordpres base themes I've tested. Could you maybe give me and advice, where should I search to find the solution for my theme? I'm using Atomion-Theme.

Comment: You should inspect your theme files searching for `woocommerce_single_product_summary` or ask the theme authors…

Comment: I've tried to inspect it already and found the hook: `add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );` but Its exact the same.